# how to improve performance when rewrite join SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlperformance

Suppose I have 2 table need to join. There are 2 way to write the sql:

```
select * from taba a join tabb b on a.id =b.id where ...
select * from taba a, tabb b where a.id = b.id and ...
```

which one has better performance or this is only syntax issue with different SQL standard regardless of performance?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference in terms of performance between these two approaches. I stopped to use ANSI 86 syntax long time ago. ANSI 92 syntax (`[INNER] / LEFT OUTER / ... JOIN`) it's more clear and  for `INNER / LEFT / RIGHT` and `FULL` join the `ON` [sub]clause is mandatory -> this means you can't forget to write the join predicate (at least in SQL Server). Instead, using the old syntax you could forget to write the join predicate into `WHERE`. This way you could get a *nice* cartesian product.

Comment: You can google for implicit and explicit joins. Usually the query planner will resolve to the same join in either case, but that's not always true. Ideally, whenever you want a join, you should make it explicit (...FROM TABLE A JOIN TABLE B ON B.A_ID = A.A_ID...), since that's how you want the query planner to resolve those in any case. I have bumped into a few cases through exotic third-party queries where implicit join syntax, with the proper other filters etc resulted in a horrible query plan over its explicit variant. Which may of course be attributed to explicit's better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Has been already answered here

stackoverflow.com/questions/1129923/is-a-join-faster-than-a-where

The query optimizer usually use more a join than a where clause (so in theory is better the join) but the last word is said by the db engine you're using
The best advice is to try